# Display default locale value in url all the time

Tags: next.js, next-i18next

I am using [Next.js i18n-routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing) in my project and it is working perfect as

- Index -> `/`
- EN -> `/about`
- TH -> `/th/about`

But I want to display default locale value (en) in the url all the time if there is no other language

- Index page -> `/en`
- EN -> `/en/about`
- TH -> `/th/about`

Is there an option from next.js i18n or a way to do this ?

Comment: you can use the if statement on entering the user like your app.js. and then if your (if statement) returned true, you can redirect the user to your locale. but you have to make sure your project has different folders for different locales so you would have a cleaner project,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with [Prefixing the Default Locale](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#prefixing-the-default-locale)

first add this to `next.config.js`:

```
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['default', 'en', 'de', 'fr'],
    defaultLocale: 'default',
    localeDetection: false,
  },
  trailingSlash: true,
}
```

and then create a `middleware.ts` (or `.js`) file at the root or in the `src` directory (same level as your `pages`). learn more on the new Next.js [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware)

```
// middleware.ts

import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'

const PUBLIC_FILE = /\.(.*)$/

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  if (
    req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/_next') ||
    req.nextUrl.pathname.includes('/api/') ||
    PUBLIC_FILE.test(req.nextUrl.pathname)
  ) {
    return
  }

  if (req.nextUrl.locale === 'default') {
    const locale = req.cookies.get('NEXT_LOCALE') || 'en'

    return NextResponse.redirect(
      new URL(`/${locale}${req.nextUrl.pathname}${req.nextUrl.search}`, req.url)
    )
  }
}
```

now if there is no specified locale it will fall back to the user locale or `en`

you can see this example in action here: [image: Edit epic-lumiere-b94rw4]

Comment: The option `localeDetection` uses the `Accept-Language` header (browser setting) to find a matching locale for the user from your list in `locales`. If you deactivate `localeDetection` every user with 'de' or 'fr' in its `Accept-Language` header will be redirected to "en" although you have a matching locale for them. - Is there no solution that uses `localeDetection` but redirects to the "defaultLocale" and displays it in the URL if there is no matching locale?